# My documents target - how can i change it to open my web site

Tags: directory, documents

I have created a web site that ( for local use on my computer ) that  navigates through  the files in the My documents folder via regular links .I would like to change the way my documents folder opens now in such way that if I double click on My documents folder I would like my web to come up and use it as interface .Is there a way to do this ?
Thank you
Adrian

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773773/make-sure-a-href-local-file-is-opened-outside-of-browser  is this a duplicate? btw this would only work for you on your own local PC -- <a href=file:///C:/Folder>Local Folder</a>

Comment: and if I would like to make it available for others on the LAN?

Comment: How can you if the file resides on a local pc. The only such feature would be to setup a network share where u can access file using machine name folder which is covered on first link I sent u

Comment: Hi ..I am in a LAN ..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its lack of knowledge on web technologies and browsers.

I am really unsure of the reasons of taking this route - you could try :

```
<a href=file://///SERVER/folder/file.extension>LAN FILE</a>
```

but to be honest i am unsure why you can not run a web server on the machine that you wish to serve the pages.

So lets say you have a lan of 3 machines

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
```

You wish to use 10.0.0.1 as the master which servers the pages - install apache web server or IIS if its windows then put a page in the DocumentRoot which points to

```
<a href=/somefolder>Some folder</a>
```

where this /somefolder is a folder within the document root of the default site.

you can then go to the browser on any other LAN hit

http:// 10.0.0.1 and it will show that page with the link which is then viewable on local browser of the remote machines... files being served from 10.0.0.1

You could go a step further and look into internal DNS or hacking the local hosts file on the remaining machine and pointing an entry like

```
10.0.0.1 intranet
```

so when any of the machines hit http:// intranet  - they hit 10.0.0.1

Comment: yes ..it is lack of knowledge..that is why I am here..Thank you..i am learning fast..ok ..so the whole scenario is this ..I have a folder on the my drive that everybody on the LAN currently has access to it.What I am planing to do is that when they double click that specific folder ..I want my web page to open ..instead of the folder contents..this is it ...thank you

Comment: so rather than give out your \\networkname\folder give out  a url for them to put into browser which is actually file:///tmp/  so rather than a http url its a file url first get the file url working locally from your machine that connects to your own local machine and loads folder then give out that url

Comment: if they click on the folder using windows it will only show folder view - with its contents if the folder has an index.html page it will show up like any other files - the html files and naming such as index.html etc are all handled /configured by the web server. I would suggest installing and playing around with apache too